# How to create incident in servicenow using chatbot

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have created a chatbot in C#, which is configured to Luis and gives some kind of reply when a question is asked. But i wanted to create incident in Servicenow using this chatbot.Chatbot asks some questions like 'what is the issue?' or 'short description'.The user input should be taken and create incident in service now and return created Incident number through bot to the user.Here the chatbot should completely act as an interface between user and service now.I am able to add dailogues to bot but cannot create incident using bot in Servicenow.As i am beginner,i am unable to write code to call rest api from service now.Can you please help me in developing code?

Answer (score 0):

The Virtual Assistant is available via the [Bot Framework Solutions repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/botframework-solutions#readme) available in C# and JS/Typescript, along with additional templates, solution accelerators and skills to help build custom conversational experiences.
Add any of the sample Skills provided in the Bot Framework Solutions repository to your Virtual Assistant. Please follow the servicenow [ITSM](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/samples/itsm/) skill with VA.

The Virtual Assistant is used for a variety of scenarios including:

Employee-facing Enterprise Assistant. An Employee Assistant experiences integrated into existing conversation canvases (e.g. Teams, Web Chat, Slack) enabling employees to manage their calendars, find available meeting rooms, find people with specific skills or perform HR-related operations, with integration with O365, Dynamics PowerApps, ServiceNow, and other IT providers for common enterprise-oriented tasks.